# How to print communicatin path between same areas in brain model created with ggseg()

Tags: r, graph, connectivity

I would like to represent a brain sketch with R with atlas coordinates I have found through literature and draw some directional paths between those nodes.

I know that there are options thanks to which draw this interactive brain model in R but I do not have any idea on how to proceed in this direction?

Is there anyone that knows how to draw this neural patterns with some customed atlas?

More or less the final effect would be something like this?

[image]

I know that there is a subset of packages that can allows this visualization but I do not know how to use them.

```
    install.packages("remotes")
    remotes::install_github("LCBC-UiO/ggseg")
    install.packages('ggseg3d')
install.packages('ggsegExtra')

library(ggseg3d)
library(ggsegExtra)
ggplot() +
  geom_brain(atlas = dk) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 4)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 8))
```